# Comparing Three Columns and Copy Pasting data

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am using below code which is comparing three columns values and copy pasting the 4th column data into other column.

My code is working fine but it is slow to perform the processing and takes much time and sometimes Not Responding window appears.

Any help to fix the problem will be appreciated

```
 Sub rowMatch()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
        Dim a As String, b As String, c  As Date
        For i = 3 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
    
            a = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
        b = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
        c = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value

        For j = 3 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 98).End(xlUp).Row
        
            If ws2.Cells(j, 98).Value = a _
               And ws2.Cells(j, 103).Value = b _
               And ws2.Cells(j, 114).Value = c _
               Then
                ws2.Cells(j, 120).Value = ws.Cells(j, 18).Value
            End If
        Next j

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the size of data?

Comment: Its more than 10,000.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the data please? As @PavloSlavynskyy points out, VBA might not be the best option here for performance

Comment: Sure please here is the [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ck_8FPHBB-9nJRKW0Hz9iZta3acT7VEp/view?usp=sharing)  @Greedo

Comment: @Valiant actually l meant if you could add this info to the question, perhaps as a [markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/354801)? Also you haven't included sheet3. Are your tables formatted as real Excel tables? (NB you can create md tables from Excel [automatically](https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Lookup by Comparing Multiple Columns (Array Loop)

**Intro**

- Although I would agree with most of Pavlo Slavynskyy's points (the screen updating is kind of debatable since you're using the fast
  'copy-by-assignment method' i.e. `dCell.Value = sCell.Value`, but it's good to know about it; and I have almost never used `VLookup` since there is the less restricting, brilliant `Application.Match`), you have made **a crucial mistake** with the loops. But let's keep it slow.

**The Workbook**

- Your worksheets are not qualified i.e. they 'point' ('belong') to the `ActiveWorkbook` which could be any workbook.
- Try the following experiment:

  - In `Excel`, open your workbook.
  - Open a new workbook.
  - Go to the `Visual Basic Editor` and run your code.
  - It will try to find the worksheets in the new workbook and probably raise
    `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`.
- In `VBA`, to reference the workbook containing this code, you use `ThisWorkbook`:

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  ```
- Since you're dealing with just **one** workbook, `wb` is just fine. No need for additional characters.

**The Worksheets**

- First of all, I love `ws` but only if there is only **one** worksheet. Using `ws` and `ws2` is kind of confusing, which is which? Where am I reading from and where am I writing to?
- I've adopted a `Source-Destination` concept, so I will use `sws` for the source and `dws` for the destination worksheets. You can create your own concept but you should be consistent about it.
- From the line `ws2.Cells(j, 120).Value = ws.Cells(j, 18).Value` it is obvious that `ws2` is you r `Destination` worksheet (`dws`) and `ws` is your `Source` worksheet (`sws`).

**Efficiency: `If` Statement**

- If you write an `If` statement in one line e.g. ...

  ```
  If A = 0 And B = 0 And C = 0 Then
  ```

  ... you have shortened the code, but on each loop, the code evaluates all three expressions, even if already `A` or `B` is not 0. For this simple example, there will be no practical difference in the efficiency but keep it in mind when you'll have more complex expressions.

**Efficiency: The Mistake**

- To make the code more efficient, you want to access (read from, especially write to) the worksheets as few times as possible, but your loops do the opposite.
- Firstly, you don't want to first loop through the rows in the columns of the source worksheet because you are trying to write to ('to fill') the cells of the destination worksheet.
- Secondly, now when you loop through the rows in the columns of the destination worksheet when a value (in this case 3 values are matched) is found, you don't need to loop any longer (it's found), so use `Exit For`:

  ```
  If Something Then ' e.g. value found
      Do Whatever
      Exit For ' stop looping
  End If
  ```

  ... to exit the loop.

**The `Split` Function**

- When you have a list in a string, e.g.,...

  ```
  Dim sNamesList As String: sNamesList = "John,Peter,Mary"
  ```

  ... you can easily write the values to an array using the `Split` function ...

  ```
  Dim sNames() As String: sNames = Split(sNamesList, ",")
  ```

  ... but be careful, any spaces inside will not be truncated.
- The resulting array is **always** a (1D) **zero-based** array.

**Efficiency: Using Arrays**

- By introducing arrays into your code, you will reduce accessing the worksheets to the minimum.
- You can read each range into an array (in one go) as simple as:

  ```
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:A10")
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
  ```
- In this case, the expression `rg.Value` alone is (has created) already a 2D one-based array with ten rows and one column containing the values of the range.
- **Note** that this is not true if the range contains only one cell (see the `GetRange` function for details).
- Knowing this, you can now loop through the elements of the arrays (in memory) instead of the cells of the worksheet and vastly improve the performance of the code.
- Similarly, you can write the values of a 2D one-based array to the worksheet in one go:

  ```
   Dim rg As Range: rg.Resize(Ubound(Data, 1), Ubound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
  ```

  ... or in our case, since there is only one column per 2D array, you can simplify:

  ```
   Dim rg As Range: rg.Resize(Ubound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
  ```

**Readability**

- To make the code more readable you can create your helper procedures which you may use in some other projects, e.g. `RefColumn` and `GetRange`.

**Miscellaneous**

- The code is written according to your posted code.
- To use it in your provided sample file, change the following:

  - `"Sheet3"` to `"Sheet2"`
  - `"R"` to `"Q"`
  - `"Sheet2"` to `"Sheet1"`

**The Main Code**

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub LookupMultiColumnsCompare()
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Lookup Multi Columns Compare"
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const sFirst As String = "N3"
    Const scColsList As String = "N,O,P" ' 14, 15, 16 add more (or less)
    Const svCol As String = "R" ' 18
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "CT3"
    Const dcColsList As String = "CT,CY,DJ" ' 98, 103, 114 ' add more
    ' *** Triple-check the following because in this column the data
    ' will be overwritten! Remember, there is no undo.
    Const dvCol As String = "DP" ' 120
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook containing this code ('ThisWorkbook').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim WasSuccessful As Boolean
    Dim n As Long ' Compare Columns Arrays Counter (Source, Destination, Loop)
        
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim scCols() As String: scCols = Split(scColsList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(scCols)
    
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To nUpper)
        
    For n = 0 To nUpper
        sData(n) = GetRange(srg.EntireRow.Columns(scCols(n)))
    Next n
    Dim svData As Variant: svData = GetRange(srg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol))
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = RefColumn(dfCell)
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = drg.Rows.Count
    Dim dcCols() As String: dcCols = Split(dcColsList, ",")
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(0 To nUpper)
    
    For n = 0 To nUpper
        dData(n) = GetRange(drg.EntireRow.Columns(dcCols(n)))
    Next n
    Dim dvData As Variant: ReDim dvData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    ' You could speed up the code if the values will always stay the same
    ' once they are written i.e. if you already have found the matches
    ' the first time and you don't need to modify them, by rather reading
    ' the 'Value' column range into the array.
    ' Instead of the previous line use the following...
    'Dim dvData As Variant: dvData = GetRange(drg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol))
    ' ... and test the value of each item in the array before looping further
    ' by adding a new 'If' statement below the line 'For dr = 1 To drCount':
    ' 'If Len(dvData(dr, 1)) = 0 Then"'. Don't forget about its 'End If'.
    
    ' Loop
    
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            For n = 0 To nUpper
                dValue = dData(n)(dr, 1)
                ' Dependent on your data, some of the following 'If' statements
                ' may be redundant but they should slow down the code,
                ' so think twice before removing (uncommenting) them.
                If IsError(dValue) Then Exit For ' exclude error values
                If Len(dValue) = 0 Then Exit For ' exclude blanks
                sValue = sData(n)(sr, 1)
                If IsError(sValue) Then Exit For ' exclude error values
                If IsDate(sValue) Then
                    If IsDate(dValue) Then
                        ' The tricky date part when it contains time.
                        If Round(CDbl(sValue), 6) <> Round(CDbl(sValue), 6) Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If sValue <> dValue Then Exit For
                End If
                
            Next n
            ' Note that if the loop was not interrupted, 'n = nUpper + 1'.
            If n > nUpper Then
                dvData(dr, 1) = svData(sr, 1)
            End If
        Next sr
    Next dr
    
    ' Overwrite the values in destination with values in the array.
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = drg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    dvrg.Value = dvData
    
    WasSuccessful = True
    
InfoExit:

    If WasSuccessful Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet successfully updated.", _
            vbInformation, ProcTitle
    Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong." & vbLf _
            & "Double-check the values in the constants section of the code.", _
            vbCritical, ProcTitle
    End If

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume InfoExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

End Function
```

**Some Toys**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the Excel column string from a (column) number.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnString( _
    ByVal ColumnNumber As Long) _
As String ' only '-2147483648#' crashes it!?
    
    Dim Remainder As Long
    Do
        Remainder = (ColumnNumber - 1) Mod 26
        GetColumnString = Chr(Remainder + 65) & GetColumnString
        ColumnNumber = Int((ColumnNumber - Remainder) \ 26)
    Loop Until ColumnNumber = 0

End Function

Sub GetColumnStringTEST()
    Debug.Print GetColumnString(120)
    Debug.Print GetColumnString(16384) ' max for 'Excel'
    Debug.Print GetColumnString(2147483647) ' max for 'Long'
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the Excel column number from a (column) string.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnNumber( _
    ByVal ColumnString As String) _
As Long
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' too many chars: "Run-time error '6': Overflow"
    
    Dim ColumnStringLength As Long: ColumnStringLength = Len(ColumnString)
    
    Dim n As Long
    Dim CharNumber As Long
    Dim CharIndex As Long
    Dim ColumnNumber As Long
    For n = ColumnStringLength To 1 Step -1
        CharNumber = Asc(UCase(Mid(ColumnString, n))) - 64
        If CharNumber >= 1 Then
            If CharNumber <= 26 Then
                ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + CharNumber * 26 ^ CharIndex
                CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    GetColumnNumber = ColumnNumber

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Sub GetColumnNumberTEST()
    Debug.Print GetColumnNumber("DP")
    Debug.Print GetColumnNumber("XFD") ' max for 'Excel'
    Debug.Print GetColumnNumber("FXSHRXW") ' max for 'Long'
End Sub
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @Toby Speight: Thanks for pointing that out. I never read it on this site. I will edit my answer ASAP, possibly tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

#### Indents

Always keep the code properly indented. You'll spend much more time fixing some stupid error caused by improperly indented code then you'll save on not indenting it.
This code looks like the only line in `For i` loop is `a = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value`, but in fact all the code except for the final line is in this loop. Don't make readers struggle to read the code.

#### Variable names

`a`, `b` and `c` are bad names. If you know what kind of data is in those columns - please, name them according to the content - like `name`, `lastName` and `dateOfBirth`.

#### Magic numbers

What are 14, 15, 98, 114? Some cells indices? What if you'll change something in the file - are you going to redo all the code because of that? Creating constants will allow you to make the code more flexible:

```
Const wsStartRow As Integer = 3
Const wsEndCellCol As Integer = 14
...
For i = wsStartRow To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, wsEndCellCol).End(xlUp).Row
```

#### Stop screen updates

Well, that's the cause of your problem: the screen updates when you change values, and screen updates are slow. You can easily stop it:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and don't forget to turn it in the end:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

#### Other ways

You can concatenate values in the cells into a new column to make use of built-in functions like VLOOKUP.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborating and highlighting my mistakes. I used your way but the problem is still same.